# AnyLogic - Change Color of agent, depending on type

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent: a package. This package has an option list "packageType" with name: TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3.

I have a parameter p_type (int). I have a function: f_getItemColor and a function f_init.

[image: function f_getItemColor]

[image: function f_init]

I have three different sources that create all types my agents (Package).I do not know if my source creates all types of agent.

[image: source]

Maybe it is not the function that is my problem, but the source that does not generate the packets correctly. I have not been able to solve it.

I can't get the colour of my package to be different depending on the type. What do I have to change?

Comment: Well, do you set `p_Type` in your source blocks for the agents?

Comment: yes, each source has another input: 0,1 or 2! I put On at exit: agent.set_p_type(0);

Comment: Where do you call `f_init`? Maybe you call it before assigning the value of `p_Type`, so each agent will be colored based on the default value.

Comment: If each  source does `On at exit: agent.set_p_type(0)` then you have the problem right there, no?

Comment: I have three different sources: source one has the code with input value 0, source two has the code with the input value 1 and source 3 has the code with the input value 2.